# Do all compilers support goto label addresses?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction, goto

I was looking at this block of code:

```
int main() {
    void *labels[] = { &&label1, &&label2 };

    goto *labels[1];

  label1:
    printf("Label 1\n");

  label2:
    printf("Label 2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if this is a normal thing and can be expected in any compiler.

Comment: It is not a standard C code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why would you want to use such a beast? While it might be debatable to what extent a `goto` is acceptable, using it with variables holding the address would clearly be a no-go in any code review.

Comment: [`warning: taking the address of a label is non-standard [-Wpedantic]`](https://godbolt.org/z/he6j4b4sY)

Comment: @AviBerger There's no use case for it?

Comment: It is non-standard. It cannot be expected in any compiler unless it is specifically documented that that compiler has this "not officially in the language" feature. There could be a use case for it. But it's non-portable & likely won't be recognized by others looking at the code. You'd need to make a really strong case to try it, rather than using another approach; & would still likely get shot down for trying such a stunt.

Comment: @Gerhardh: CPython uses this to achieve, IIRC, roughly a 15-20% speed up by dramatically reducing bytecode dispatch overhead relative to the "infinite loop around a `switch`" used when computed-gotos aren't available. Branch prediction on the `switch` is essentially useless, but there is a tendency for certain bytecodes to repeatedly be followed by other specific bytecodes (sometimes the same, sometimes a different code), and since branch prediction typically works on a per-instruction level, each opcode ends up with its own (useful) branch prediction, which helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it's one of the `GCC` compilers features , refer to [labels as Values in GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values) , they clearly state that :

> You can get the address of a label defined in the current function (or a containing function) with the unary operator ‘&&’. The value has type void *. This value is a constant and can be used wherever a constant of that type is valid. For example:
>
> ```
> void *ptr;
> /* … */
> ptr = &&foo;
> ```

where `foo` is just a label , so yeah , you can deal with labels as addresses in `GCC` compiler according to the manual.

even they have this example that is nearly same as yours as they stated that :

> One way of using these constants is in initializing a static array
> that serves as a jump table:
>
> ```
>  static void *array[] = { &&foo, &&bar, &&hack };
> ```
>
> Then you can select a label with indexing, like this:
>
> ```
>  goto *array[i];
> ```

but it's a feature in `GCC` compiler , so whatever the compiler you use , refer to its manual and you should know if this feature is supported or not.

but also remember that , it's not a good practice to use `label` and `goto` in your code if you are coding for critical system which sticks to strict rules as according to **MISRA C** in section **8.15 Control flow** , they clearly stated that :

> Rule 15.1 The goto statement should not be used

so then it might be better to say that using `goto` is a fine practice when used thoughtfully and judiciously so long as it is not applied in a codebase that observes such strict guidelines.

Comment: but even the linux kernel has code contributed by professionals that use goto

Comment: @FariyaAchhab , notice that MISRA C also stated in **rule 17.1** that `The features of <stdarg.h> shall not be used` , but this header file is used very often , notice that MISRA C is a specification to C code standard that's meant to be used when implementing critical systems , many embedded systems projects rely on MISRA C rules. so it's nothing that you must stick to , but it's advisory especially when coding for a critical system.